# How would you show battles that take place in temperatures of between -120 to -150 Degrees Celsius?

Tags: aliens, combat, temperature, mind-control

So basically what I'm talking about here are my Enslaver Aliens. This brings this back to my previous post. Such Aliens, when they appear, have an area wide effect. Whilst their main ability is to dominate human minds and people are haven't done regular training they also have the powers of telepathy, teleportstion and telekinesis. Said mind control turns people into something similar tk a zombie.

As long as they're alive, everything from a kilometre to a hundred kilometres radius drops in temperature to -120 to -140 Degrees Celcius. So it's very cold. Such battles can last, against the Enslaver between half a day to up to seven weeks.

A Newborn Enslaver is an alien the size of a large dog that can only cause the temperature,  within a kilometre of its to drop to -120 Celsisus. It usually takes half a day to kill and can only control a thousand or so people, without proper mental conditioning at a time. It can also only do some short range teleportation once an hour.

On the other hand a full mentally matured and elderly Enslaver is something ths size of a four storey building. It's mere presence drops the temperatures of everything within 100 kilometres of it to -150 celsius. It takes about 50-500 days of fighting to kill with modern tech and can enslave up to 100,000 unprepared people at a single time. It can also teleporting, in the short range every 36 seconds.

Given this how would you show such battle conditions?

Comment: How do you mean "show". This seems like a pure writing question, nothing to do with solving a worldbuilding problem. Try [writing.se].

Comment: This is fully 30 degrees colder than the coldest recorded temperature on earth. CO2 will freeze into dry ice. I don’t think there’s a level of cold weather gear that would make this plausibly survivable. Combat would be via long range artillery from outside the area of effect.

Comment: Wouldn't this draw the heat out of bodies, freezing people solid? Also, what's the point of controlling humans that can't survive in the enslaver's proximity? Take away protective gear from the humans and send in drone attack vehicles with nuclear weapons or similar overpowered attacks.

Comment: "everything from a kilometre to a hundred kilometres radius drops in temperature to -120 to -140 Degrees Celcius" - So Enslaver Alien would be encased in layers of water ice and dry ice. Also, any humans around would be frozen solid.

Answer (score 3):

**Nerds arguing about ballistics.**

Your battle would be depicted by showing persons getting the space shuttles out of mothballs and loaded with ordinance to drop, people fitting out cruise missiles that can turn dumb when frozen and continue on their trajectory, people swapping out the nuclear warheads on ICBMs with warheads appropriate for use against the Enslavers and so on.   I like the scene where a roomful of nerds carefully deorbits a large satellite to precisely crash on the Enslaver.  A team would be sent to update and resupply the Soviet moon cannon.

If everything is frozen solid I do not see how this will be an infantry battle because soldiers of both sides would be frozen solid.   If the Enslaver can suck the heat out of everything I imagine this would be true for internal combustion engines as well.   @Dwkraus' point about slaves is true too - what is the point of having slavesicles?  I guess they might be aesthetically pleasing for the Enslaver and they wil lkeep well.

A benefit to the heat sucking is that the location of individual Enslavers will be easy to determine using thermal / infrared cameras on satellites.

The depiction of these battles will be a depiction of people around the world figuring out how to make war on the surface from the vantage point of space.  That sounds like a fine fiction to me!